# How would our vision be improved if our photoreceptors were not backwards?

Tags: human-biology, human-physiology, eyes, human-eye, optics

I'm curious to how much better human eyesight would be if the nerves from our rods and cones were correctly placed behind the receptors?

Are there any Animal Models with correctly placed photoreceptors that we can use as a benchmark?

Comment: Octopuses have nerves in the arrangement you want. However I do not know any more detail. Please see if you can find some literature on this topic.